# Chained expressions in polars not working

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to learn a bit about using polars so I had a simple problem to test it out where I ultimately want to run a `group_by` operation on the data.

While analysis the data I create a few extra series from the initial data by adding and then cumulating.

I understand that when you want to use a newly created variable with an expression, it needs to be in another chained `with_columns` but I can't seem to make it work.

I have the following example code which I believe should be correct, but fails. Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

data = np.random.random((50,5))
df = pl.from_numpy(data, schema=["id", "sampling_time", "area", "val1", "area_corr"])

(df
.with_columns([
    pl.col("id").cast(pl.Int32),
    pl.Series(name="total_area", values=df.select(pl.col("area") + pl.col("area_corr"))),
])
.with_columns([
    pl.Series(name="cumulative_area", values=df.select(pl.cum_sum("total_area")) / 0.15),
])
.with_columns([
    pl.Series(name="parcel_id", values=df.select(pl.col("cumulative_area").cast(pl.Int32))),
])
)
```

However the snippet fails with the following stacktrace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-8e61e84b3c85>", line 7, in <module>
    pl.Series(name="cumulative_area", values=df.select(pl.cum_sum("total_area")) / 0.15),
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py", line 8142, in select
    return self.lazy().select(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\polars\lazyframe\frame.py", line 1940, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
polars.exceptions.ColumnNotFoundError: total_area
Error originated just after this operation:
DF ["id", "sampling_time", "area", "val1"]; PROJECT */5 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

I don't understand why the newly created `total_area` series is not found.

I'm on polars 0.20.7 with python 3.8.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Diagnostics.**

Your code fails as you explicitly reference `df` in the second call of [`pl.DataFrame.with_columns`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html). However, the result of the previous `with_columns` evaluation is never reassigned to the variable `df`. Especially, `df` doesn't contain the *total_area* column.

**Solution.**

Usually, you only construct `pl.Series` objects within `with_columns` if the data you'd like to add to the dataframe is stored in an external variable and not computed from the data in the dataframe.

In your example, all data necessary to create the new columns already exists in the data and you can compute their value using the expressions API.

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("id").cast(pl.Int32),
        total_area=pl.col("area") + pl.col("area_corr")
    )
    .with_columns(
        cumulative_area=pl.cum_sum("total_area") / 0.15
    )
    .with_columns(
        parcel_id=pl.col("cumulative_area").cast(pl.Int32)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems much simpler! Does the same reasoning apply to the `pl.select`?

Comment: @jpmorr Great! And - yes - it does.